# How to set up testcontainers with Junit4 in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I am trying to set up test containers with junit4 in Spring-Boot in order to run my integration tests. I am using MongoDB in my application this is why I am using `MongoDB Container` on my example. This is the code I have so far:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MongoDBContainer;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class AppTest {

    @Rule
    public MongoDBContainer container = new MongoDBContainer("mongo:4.0.10");

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        container.start();
        String address = container.getHost();
        Integer port = container.getFirstMappedPort();

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("example", "example");
    }

}
```

Although I am following the documentation, when I run the test to test if the container is up and running I get the following error:

```
2020-09-14 19:00:42.392  INFO   --- [           main] org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory   : Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 19.03.6
  API Version: 1.40
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
  Total Memory: 15731 MB
2020-09-14 19:01:12.856 ERROR   --- [           main] o.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper  : Timeout out waiting for Ryuk. Ryuk's log:
2020/09/14 17:00:42 Pinging Docker...
2020/09/14 17:00:42 Docker daemon is available!
2020/09/14 17:00:42 Starting on port 8080...
2020/09/14 17:00:42 Started!


org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed

    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:330)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:311)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.starting(GenericContainer.java:1022)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.FailureDetectingExternalResource$1.evaluate(FailureDetectingExternalResource.java:29)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerFetchException: Can't get Docker image: RemoteDockerImage(imageName=mongo:4.0.10, imagePullPolicy=DefaultPullPolicy())
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1279)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.logger(GenericContainer.java:613)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:320)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to Ryuk at localhost:32773
    at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper.start(ResourceReaper.java:176)
    at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:168)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
    at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.listImagesCmd(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.maybeInitCache(LocalImagesCache.java:68)
    at org.testcontainers.images.LocalImagesCache.get(LocalImagesCache.java:32)
    at org.testcontainers.images.AbstractImagePullPolicy.shouldPull(AbstractImagePullPolicy.java:18)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:59)
    at org.testcontainers.images.RemoteDockerImage.resolve(RemoteDockerImage.java:26)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.getResolvedValue(LazyFuture.java:20)
    at org.testcontainers.utility.LazyFuture.get(LazyFuture.java:27)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.getDockerImageName(GenericContainer.java:1277)
    ... 20 more
```

Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong here? I am not sure why it fails to get the docker image

Comment: Have you tried disabling Ryuk https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/700#issuecomment-458918523 ?

Comment: What is your testcontainers version?

Comment: 1.14.3 version @VitalyChura

Comment: @RomanKonoval I will check it

Comment: I don't think disabling Ryuk is the solution. If you still have that issue, could you share some example project?

Comment: @VitalyChura hello what do you mean by example project?

Comment: I meant a simple project I could open id IDE and try running it, but probably it's not required.

I understand that you try running that test on your local PC. Do you run docker with sudo or have you added your user to docker group?

Something is wrong with permissions, another option is to try disabling Ryuk as mentioned above but it's really not recommended (since it handles container cleanup at the end of the test).

Comment: @VitalyChura disabling Ryuk did it

Comment: @RomanKonoval if you write it as answer I can accept the solution

Comment: I asked the question to better understand the problem and to help analyze it. Disabling is not a generic solution that I would recommend.